# Why are changing Zabbix's triggers status to unknown?

Tags: monitoring, database, zabbix

In zabbix I have an item which i create some triggers for that on below conditions:

1. {Server Template:mysql.slowqueries.last(0,1800)}>{Server Template:mysql.slowqueries.last(0)}
2. {Server Template:mysql.slowqueries.last(0,1800)}<{Server Template:mysql.slowqueries.last(0)}
3. {Server Template:mysql.slowqueries.avg(900)}=0
4. {Server Template:mysql.slowqueries.last(0,1800)}={Server Template:mysql.slowqueries.last(0)}

The first one's Severity is define as disaster. when the trigger is run its status is UNKNOWN in **Monitoring > Events**. What is the problem? why? how to solve it?

Comment: Lots of slow queries is not a disaster. The datacenter burning down is a disaster.

Answer (score 2):

If trigger evaluation fails for some reason, you should see an error message in "Configuration" -> "Triggers", on the right hand side:

[image]

In this case, if you have just created "mysql.slowqueries" item and it does not yet have data older than half an hour, function "last(0,1800)" (which returns the last value half an hour ago) is going to fail. Once it has data that is older than half an hour, it should work properly.

If this does not help, please post the error message you see and also your Zabbix version.

Comment: Thank you. As i said in my question trigger's status in **Monitoring -> Events** is **UNLNOWN** and in **Configuration->Triggers** every thing is OK. this item get values for too long.